# PHP query to search multiple tables in MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I've read through a few of these responses and I'm not sure I'm understanding how to go about this. I'm completely new to this, and feel a little lost. Right now, I have a PHP query that echos data from one table. I have a database that generates a new table every day. I need to be able to constantly search that database for values across all tables.

Here is my code at present:

```
<?php
$dbc = mysql_connect ('localhost','root','abcde');

if (!$dbc){
    die('Not Connected:' . mysql_error ());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db ('game_database', $dbc);

if (!$db_selected) {
    die ("Can't Connect :" .mysql_error());
}

$query="SELECT * FROM `03-31-14` WHERE GAME='Clash of Clans'";

$result=mysql_query($query);

if (!$query){
    die ("Can't Connect :" .mysql_error());
}

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row['GAME'];
    echo $row['REVENUE2'];
    echo $row['ARPU'];
    echo $row['DAILY_NEW_USERS'];
}
?>
```

Is there a way to modify this so I can search for similar information across all of my tables?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you really have a table named `03-31-14`

Comment: `PRO-TIP` Don't use any function that starts with `mysql_` period!

Comment: ...why exactly are you generating a new table every day?  This seems like a very not ideal way of doing this.  Just do one table and add a date column.

Comment: try create another query with another select from your other tables and echo the results.

Comment: Further to @MikeB's comment - instead of creating a new table every day with the date as the name (another **Pro Tip**: use a name that actually describes what's in the table), add a `date` or `date_added` column to a single table and update that - it will make it **much** easier to query.

Comment: as example use $query1 = "SELECT * FROM 'table_name' WHERE 'your_criteria'"; Or you want to compare data from similar tables? Search how you can INNER JOIN tables with similar data.

Comment: I would echo the comment made by @AndrewNee You can probably simplify your system greatly by rethinking your DB schema with regards to the one table per day concept.  Why is this even necessary? You really should explain that question and be 100% certain this is the way to go before proceeding any further.

Comment: I agree with @Fred, partly because I suffer the same thing here. A new user reads my substantial answer, but does not think it is worth responding to it. If everyone did that, we'd not have a community left, I'd wager. (Positive) moral of the story: always respond to people who help you `:)`.

Comment: Well said @halfer That's what a community is all about. We take the time to find the problem and outline it with a descriptive text; most of the time when it's needed. Small typos on the other hand are evident.

Comment: I wish I could downvote twice

Comment: @Fred-ii- Hey, guys. Sorry to cause everyone grief. I'm completely new to this. I'll try to be more grateful for you wisdom in the future! Tbh I'm sort of in panic-mode, since I absolutely need to figure this out ASAP for my job. Again, sorry to not follow community protocol. All your answers have been super helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always run a while loop through all of your tables.
since you named your tables consecutive numbers then you could do something like this:

```
$ i=1;
while(i<30){
    if($query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `03-31-".i."` WHERE GAME='Clash of Clans'")){

    //extra code to handle values in this table

    }else break;
    i++;
}
```

This would handle all of the values in one month, and you could obviously add use more string manipulation to run it for whatever date you need

Comment: Hmm, but what would happen if there wasn't a table for a certain day?  Wouldn't that blow things up?

Comment: No, you could always check to see if the table has values or is null and break out of the while loop if it is NULL

Comment: I think there's something wrong with my syntax but I can't puzzle it out.

Comment: one thing I can tell if you copied this code exactly you would get 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 instead of 01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10

Answer (score 0):

[UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) lets you merge several SELECT statements into one result set. So you'd do something like

```
SELECT * FROM `3-14-2014` WHERE GAME='Clash of Clans' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM `3-15-2014` WHERE GAME='Clash of Clans' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM `3-16-2014` WHERE GAME='Clash of Clans' 
...
```

But before you actually use this, you might want to revisit your database design. The whole thing would probably be more efficient and more maintainable if you only used one table for all of these records and just added a date column.